# How to set different target values for different days in Splunk?

Tags: splunk

how can I change the target column in different target values you can see in the picture below. 
How is it possible to set different values for the different days?

[Result in Splunk with changes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hita1.png)

index=*************
| bin _time span=1d
| stats count by _time
| eval target = 1000

Comment: It depends on what the criteria are for the target value.  Perhaps a lookup table will work.

Answer (score 0):

Using a lookup would be the best approach, as Rich said.

Alternatively, you could use a case statement, if the list is not going to be too long.

```
index=************* | bin _time span=1d | stats count by _time | eval target = case(
_time="2019-09-23",500,
_time="2019-09-24",2000,
_time="2019-09-25",1300,
_time="2019-09-26",400,
_time="2019-09-27",1500,
_time="2019-09-29",300 )
```